# The Metapost image in XeLaTeX is offset

Tags: graphics, xetex, miktex, metapost

When I use the EPS images made by Metapost in XeLaTeX.
The image is not in the right place.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline 
        \psfig{figure=pix-1.eps} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image: Output]

If I use other EPS images not made by Metapost, I have no problem.
How can I fix the issue?

The xelatex and metapost compiler is MikTex 2.9.6210 64-bit.

EDIT: the source code of image:

```
prologues:=3;
filenametemplate "%j-%c.eps"; 

verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
etex

input TEX

TEXPRE("%&latex" & char(10) & "\documentclass{article}\begin{document}");
TEXPOST("\end{document}");

beginfig(1)
    u := 1cm;
    lx := 1u;   
    sx := -1.2;
    ex := 1.2;
    rx := (ex - sx)/40;

    drawarrow (-1.5u,0) -- (1.2u,0);
    drawarrow (0,-3u) -- (0,3u);
    drawoptions(withpen pensquare scaled 1.2);
    for i = .5 step 0.5 until 2:
        draw (sx,i*sx*sx)*lx for j = 1 upto 40:
                .. (sx + j*rx,i*((sx + j*rx)**2))*lx
            endfor;
        label.rt("a=" & decimal(i),(ex,i*ex*ex)*lx);
    endfor;
    drawoptions();
endfig;
```

Comment: that's a bit odd but why are you using `epsfig` and `\epsfig` not the standard graphics inclusion. (I doubt it makes any difference as `\epsfig` just expands to `\includegraphics` but it looks a bit odd to be using that emulation unless the document was written in the 1980's)

Comment: Use `\includegraphics` has the same result.

Comment: Yes that's expected (although using that simplifies debugging, one less layer to go through) I would guess the eps has the wrong bounding box what happens if you try your test with latex+dvips? can you make the eps (or metapost source) available somewhere?

Comment: The source code is posted above. And the eps file link is [here](http://goo.gl/3n4tFn). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XeLaTeX (actually `xdvipdfmx`) has some problems with EPS inclusion.

The fix is very simple: change

```
filenametemplate "%j-%c.eps";
```

into

```
filenametemplate "%j-%c.mps";
```

and your document can be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
\includegraphics{figure-pix-1.mps} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `.mps` extension the graphic file is read in with a different driver, which directly translates the Metapost produced Postscript code into PDF code.

Answer (score 4):

This is partially documented in xetex.def comments but the default behaviour seems wrong, however the current situation is that you need to rename the file to `.mps` extension or use the `--vorigin` option to `xdvipdfmx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}   


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline 
        \includegraphics{pix-1.eps} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

with a command line of

```
xelatex -output-driver='xdvipdfmx --mvorigin ' file
```

produces

[image]